# Skyscrapers 6x6 - Stuck at the end

Tags: logical-deduction, grid-deduction

I tried to write a program to solve a Skyscrapers puzzle. Until the last steps I always used the opposite clues. But I can't find a solution for the last cells. This is where I am:

```
    3 2 2 3 2 1

    = = = = = = 
4  |2| | |3|5|6|  1
    = = = = = = 
2  |1|6|3|2|4|5|  2
    = = = = = = 
2  |4| |6|5| | |  3
    = = = = = = 
1  |6|5|2|1|3|4|  3
    = = = = = = 
2  |5| | |6| | |  2
    = = = = = = 
3  |3|2|5|4|6|1|  2
    = = = = = = 

    3 4 2 2 1 5
```

How can I determine the last cells here? What are the steps?

I know the solution and know that my steps until here are correct

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In column 3, row 1

> The top number cannot be a 1 or that would break the skyscraper restriction. It must therefore be a 4. This makes column 2, row 1 a 1.

The rest of the puzzle can be solved via normal sudoku rules

Comment: You are right. I see it now also in my calculated pattern it was already there. I just have to add  that   2  |  X362X5  ->  2 |  436215. If you look at it like a slice.